# Other way to select from function returning table in Oracle

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

I have an Oracle function my_func() that returns table of user type.

I can select from it now this way:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(my_func(3));
```

But my project should not depend on database, and I would like to have opportunity to write this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_func(3);
```

Is there a way to do this in Oracle?

Comment: just think of TABLE as a bridge between SQL and PLSQL.  Whats the problem using TABLE? (and even if you could remove TABLE, you would still "depend on database", you are selecting from it afterall)

Comment: The point is that say in Postgres you could select * from my_func() just so. I just don't want to fix all the places in the code that contain such calls

Comment: but your code for my_func() would be different for each db platform anyway.  So you are only concerned with making selects db agnostic? (which in this case you can't).  My point is that your company is paying for Oracle, so use its functionality.  I've seen several attempts at completely agnostic db code that runs off the rails once there is more complexity/requirements in the system.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the table collection expression Table() to do this directly.

If you did not need to pass in that parameter you could encapsulate a query against the table collection expression in a view.

Otherwise, there might be a way to pass the parameter to the function via a packaged global variable but it would likely not be anything like database independent.

Answer (score 0):

You are on a different planet with oracle compared to MS SQL in programic posabilities. It is not really harder just different concepts

**example1:**

```
  PROCEDURE Get_EligPlanTypes_sp    (I_EMPLID         IN     VARCHAR2,
                                 EligPlanTypesCur OUT    CurRefType) IS

  BEGIN

--* Retrieve eligible plan types for entry into the plan object. 

   OPEN EligPlanTypesCur FOR SELECT DISPLAY_PLN_SEQ
                   ,PLAN_TYPE
                   ,OPTION_CD
                   ,ELECTION_MADE
                               FROM ENR_PARTIC_PLAN
                      WHERE EMPLID   = I_EMPLID
                           ORDER BY DISPLAY_PLN_SEQ;

    EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
             RAISE;

  END Get_EligPlanTypes_sp;
```

**Sample Function:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE dba_Functions_Package
AS


Function InstrCount         (strValue     Varchar2
                ,strTarget        Varchar2)
                RETURN NUMBER;


END dba_Functions_Package;

/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY dba_Functions_Package
AS
-- *********************************************************************
-- ***  F U N C  T I O N (InstrCount) D E C L A R A T I O N S      *****
-- *********************************************************************

Function InstrCount     (strValue     IN Varchar2
            ,strTarget        IN Varchar2)
    RETURN Number
IS
        numOccurs   Integer :=  0;
        numReturn   Number  := -1;
    BEGIN

        While numReturn != 0 Loop
            numReturn := Instr(strValue,strTarget,1,numOccurs+1);
            If numReturn <> 0 Then
                numOccurs := numOccurs + 1;
            End If;
        End Loop While;

    RETURN(numOccurs);

    EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN RAISE;

End InstrCount;



END dba_Functions_Package;

/
```

Look at  Hierarchical query. should get you along [Link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm#sthref3130)

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way in Oracle to do that withouth table().
I'd use a simple switch in the call to determine the "table" variable to select from.